# What is the default value for the "left" property?

Tags: html, css

I try to overwrite left:0 with left:none doesn't work, other property like margin, padding work with overwriting..

I don't want to modify original css, how should solve this problem?

Comment: It shouldn't work with any of those properties. `none` isn't a valid value for any of them, and the default value for those properties *is* zero. Are you sure you know what you're doing?

Comment: The default value for `left` is `auto` IIRC

Comment: Take a look at the css with firebug.  It will show you what is inherited and what is not, and exactly where it is inherited in the css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have any value from below for left!

```
left: <length> | <percentage> | auto
```

The default (or initial as stated in the below document) value is `auto`. From this, usage of `none` is not allowed here.

For more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left

Answer (score 0):

Using `left: auto;` might sometimes help to save the day.
If your element still *plays hard*... you can hit him with an `auto !important;`